# Scrolling Settings - "Throw"

Tags: macos, trackpad

I was trying to change my scrolling settings to keep the screen from scrolling when I take my hands off the touchpad.  Right now, if I do a two-finger scroll, and take my fingers off the pad while keeping my hand moving, the screen continues to scroll, like a throw.  I would like this behavior to stop.

I have a MacBook Pro running Leopard

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the inertia for the two fingers scroll, just select "without inertia" under *Trackpad* inside the *System Preferences* :

[image: inertia]

Comment: Nice. I couldn't add a screencap, as I'm currently on an older Mac that doesn't support it so the option isn't there.

Comment: Apple release an update some days ago to enable this feature on older Mac (older, yes, but newer than 2008-2009).

Comment: Hasn't shown up on my machine, but my home MBP is the early 2008 model, so it's likely not a supported option. No biggie, since it was one of the first things I disabled on my work computer.

Answer (score 4):

In your Trackpad system preferences panel, under Two Fingers, change the "Scroll with Inertia" option. That should stop it.